add scrolling lyrics to video from subtitles (karaoke-style)
i am looking for a script or a tool that can add vertically scrolling lyrics to a video looking like this:

source
(the background should be the actual video instead of a static image)
my requirements are:

takes as input .ass or srt subtitles (ass provides word-level precision,  while srt only line-level) + a video file
batch mode operation
free/open source tool i can easily customize

I've tried burning the subs with ffmpeg, but it show only a single line of text, while i want to fill the screen with text.
I've found it is also possible to change the start/end times of the subs lines, but then i would also need to add an extra delay to each line to keep it in sync.
